# Connecting to Microsoft SQL server from R

Tags: r, sql-server

The following Python script works.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

DOMAIN_NAME = "my_domain"
USER = "my_username"
PASSWORD = "my_password"
SERVER = "server_name"
DB = "database_name"

engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pymssql://{DOMAIN_NAME}\\{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{SERVER}/{DB}")

query =sql("""
SELECT Name
FROM Products
""")
pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

I need to port it into R (to run from Rstudio), but cannot figure it out.
I prefer to use native R implementation, rather than `reticulate` package.

Looking at https://db.rstudio.com/databases/microsoft-sql-server/
I am not sure how to populate the fields in the example they provide

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "[your driver's name]",
                      Server   = "[your server's path]",
                      Database = "[your database's name]",
                      UID      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                      PWD      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
                      Port     = 1433)
```

Comment: All supported SQL Server versions (ie 2016 and later) support [R scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-r-create-script?view=sql-server-ver15) on RevolutionR's optimized runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This eventually worked. `Trusted_Connection = "True"` made the trick

```
DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
             Driver = "SQL Server",
             Server = SERVER,
             Database = DB,
             UID = glue::glue("\\{DOMAIN_NAME}/{USER}"),
             PWD = PASSWORD,
             Trusted_Connection = "True",
             port=1433
```

)

Answer (score 1):

"Driver" is the name of your ODBC driver, as you might see in your ODBC data sources app. For example, on Windows the standard SQL Server driver that comes with the OS is `SQL Server`. You can also install one from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-ver15) which will be `Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`.

The other arguments are basically the same as for your Python example.

```
DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
    Driver="SQL Server",
    Server="domain",
    Uid="your-username",
    Pwd="your-password",
    port=1433
)
```

Comment: does not work.getting Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 01S00: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute

Comment: In your example, there is no use of SERVER and DB fields which are used in Python code